# Google Chrome not letting me use setAttribute for ID's

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, jslint

I've got some JS code here. Basically, I am trying to change the ID of an element to some value from a previous variable.

Here's what I got so far;

```
function() {
  var colorarray = [ "RANDOMCOLOR_0", "RANDOMCOLOR_1", "RANDOMCOLOR_2" ];
  var RANcolorarray = colorarray[Math.rsound(Math.random() * (colorarray.length - 1))];
  document.getElementsByClassName('RANDOMCOLOR').setAttribute('id', RANcolorarray); 
}
```

This code throws an error in Chrome for line 4: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` which is weird because JsLint finds no errors.

I also tried using the other way to setting id's;

```
document.getElementsByClassName('RANDOMCOLOR').id = RANcolorarray;
```

However, although this method does not throw an error on chrome or jslint - it does not work at all after inspecting the element.. :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('RANDOMCOLOR')` returns a list of DOM nodes (even if there's only one match) so you can't just call `.setAttribute()` on the list as the list doesn't have that method.

You can either get the first item out of the list and call `.setAttribute()` on that one or use a `for` loop to iterate through the list and call it on all of them.  Of course, since you're setting the id, you should not be setting multiple elements to the same id, so I'll assume you just want one element:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('RANDOMCOLOR')[0].id = RANcolorarray;
```

Or, a little more safe:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('RANDOMCOLOR');
if (elems && elems.length) {
    elems[0].id = RANcolorarray; 
}
```

Comment: That makes a whole lot of sense! - so basically I just need to say which one in the list I want to change then, thank you.